# ElasticSearch Groovy script called from Java, how to iterate on all parameters?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

In my java code I call a groovy script that update an index elasticsearch. I pass a Map in parameter of this script.
The call in the java code is done like this :

```
// params is a Map<String, String> fullfill
params.put("date","2017-0-23");
params.put("sun","good");
request.script(new Script("myscript", ScriptType.FILE, "groovy", params));

request.upsert("{}");
request.scriptedUpsert(true);
try {
    client.update(request).get();
}
```

Then in the groovy script i do something like this :

```
newmap = ['date': date,
        'sun': sun,
         ]
```

So i create a new map and i fill it with some values of the map 'params' from java. If i create a new map it is because i want to do a little traitment on the map i passed in parameter.

But my problem is that if my java map contains a key "date" with a value "2017-08-23" i only know how to access to the value "2017-08-23" and i do this just by writting date in the script (so the key of the java map).

Is there a way to access to some element of the map that i don't know the name ? In fact I want to iterate on all the content of my java map and get the key and the value.

I read all of that page but i don't find any solution https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html

I have never use Groovy, excepted in that case, but it's seems that the content of my java map is transformed in something called "named parameter" in groovy.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Do you want to do any operations on the data while iterating thru?

Comment: Not specifically, i just want to be able to iterate on the map passed in parameter in order to get all element even if I don't know the name of them statically.

Answer (score 0):

In groovy, you can iterate over a map (or a lot of things, really) using .each.  For example:

```
def test = [one: 1, two: 2, three: 3]
test.each { k, v -> println k }
```

Prints out

```
one
two
three
```

The values are accessible in the closure (.each) as "v".  You can call your keys and values what you want in the closure, but convention says k and v are convenient.
​

Comment: I don't want to iterate on the map i create in the groovy script but in the one passed in parameter from java. So i don't have (or i personally don't know) the name of the reference.

Comment: Well I was just giving an example.  You don't have to create the map; you can do the same thing with 'params.each'.

Comment: "So i don't have (or i personally don't know) the name of the reference"
Params is the name of the variable in java but in the groovy script i don't know how to acced to the map. I only know that i can acceed to the value of each element as named parameter.